# IIS basic authentication using LDAP

Tags: iis, authentication, ldap

I have a web service which needs to use HTTP authentication with IIS. The only hurdle is that the user's credentials are in LDAP. Is there a way to configure IIS to use LDAP credentials for it's basic authentication? I thought I could set the default domain or realm to part of the LDAP connection string, but haven't had any luck.
Thanks,

-Will

Answer (score 1):

What I would do (I'm assuming you're using a third party LDAP, and that there isn't a built in way of doing this; I haven't checked) is set up [MADAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479391.aspx) and implement a custom `IUserSecurityAuthority` by extending `Madam.UserSecurityAuthorityBase` to check the credentials against LDAP.

All you will have to do is override a handful of methods to authenticate from LDAP.  If you happen to be using an LDAP Membership Provider for forms authentication, you can skip implementing that separately and use the example `MembershipSecurityAuthority` included with MADAM.

Excerpt from that example file here:

```
protected override bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
{
    return MembershipProvider.ValidateUser(userName, password);
}
```

[Potentially useful LDAP user validation code](http://forums.asp.net/p/970391/1221368.aspx)

Comment: My coworker, the original poster, has indicated to me that this is the answer he would accept if he still had access to his throwaway account.

Answer (score 0):

There is a codeplex project that looks like it has exactly what you need.

It has a great Search function so you can even test what Roles the user is in.

http://ldapwebservice.codeplex.com/